# Add a vertical image in the chapter page

Tags: graphics, chapters, titlesec

I would like to insert an image across all vertical space in the chapter page. Something like in this figure (the red line indicate the limit of the page. The black line would be where I'd insert the image):
[image]

Now I'm using the following code to make the title of the chapter:

```
    \documentclass{book}

\usepackage[includehead,paperwidth=155mm, paperheight=235mm,left=17mm,right=23mm,top=7mm,bottom=23mm,headheight=9mm]{geometry}
\special{papersize=155mm,235mm}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{titlesec} %title chapters
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\chapnumfont}{%     % define font for chapter number
    \usefont{T1}{pnc}{b}{n}%      % choose New Chancery, bold, normal shape
    \fontsize{150}{100}%          % font size 100pt, baselineskip 100pt
    \selectfont%                  % activate font
}
\colorlet{chapnumcol}{NavyBlue!75}  % color for chapter number
    
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filleft\bfseries}
    {\filleft\chapnumfont\rotatebox{60}{\textcolor{chapnumcol}{\thechapter}}}
    {-15pt}
    {\Huge}
    
\begin{document}
    
\chapter{My chapter name}
\vspace{6cm}
\begin{quotation}
    \raggedleft
    \em % optional -- to switch to emphasis (italics) mode
    "My quotation."
    
    \medskip
    \raggedleft
    made by this guy
\end{quotation}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

but I do not know how to do that image. I though in doing a minipage, but minipage only starts after the "chapter title". I saw this answer, which is similar to my purpose [Add Image to chapter title page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541609/add-image-to-chapter-title-page), but the code they show is only compatible with XeLaTeX, which I'm not using. Can anyone give me a hint on how to do that?

Also, is there any option to limit how much to the left border the title name can go?

Comment: You can scale your image  to `\paperheight`, determine the width of the scales image and use this width in `\titleformat`. The image itself would be inserted with the `esopic` package.

Comment: when adding the package eso-pic in the MWE code I provided it gives me errors "undefined control sequence. }" and "missing \begin{document}. }". Why?

Comment: I don't have (unfortunately) a crystal ball. Could you post a small , yet complete, code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: As I said, is the same code I provided in my post. I just added "\usepackage{eso-pic}" before "\usepackage{graphicx}"

Comment: ok, I updated my miktex packages, uninstalled esopic and installed again. It seems there was an error with the package I had...

Comment: Sometimes, an update in the kernel induces problems in some packages, that have to be updated to be compatible.